# Shortcut for dataframe's variables?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to write too much times `"data$..."`, I just want to write the name of the column instead of all of that (es. `"sex"` instead of `"data$sex"`).

I know it's possible (probably with a package), but I don't remember how to do that.

Comment: @I_O please don't recommend the rightfully maligned `attach()`. `dplyr`, `data.table`, `with`, all good options.

Comment: Package dplyr (rather the whole tidyverse) has you covered. In base R you have `with` (and another option I withdraw following Gregors comment ;-)  )